# maven set classes time stamp before packing the jar

Tags: maven

I want to set the time stamp of the classes and resource in a maven module, just before it's built into the jar.
I guess I can use the maven-antrun-plugin, but I'd like to see if there are better ideas.

Does anyone have an idea?

Let me add more details for the reason I need this capability.

When we build a new version for the product, we also build a patch install which compares all artifacts of previous build to current, and packages only the ones which differ.

Jars (and any zip based archive) might have the same content, but time stamp of classes and resources are part of the metadata, and cause the diff to show jars differ (when in fact, the content is identical). I want to hack the jar packing and set all classes times tamp to be constant (like 1/1/2000 00:00).

I hope this explains my need.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more what you like to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to share what I decided to do.

I will not touch the maven build, and let it build the jars as before.

What I did is implement a script in my build to compare the jars. The logic of this script is simple:

- Check arguments (jars exist)
- Extract jars to a temp folder (with a unique name)
- Run a diff on both folders
- Cleanup
- Exit with the relevant exit code (0 if same. 1 if differ)

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best solution is to adapt your tool that compute the diff to go have a look deeper in the jar ;)

I am afraid there is no other way than using the a ant file with the `touch` task to reset the file date. There is no existing plugin that sets the file date.

You could also write your own maven plugin and contribute it to the community but it is probably a bit overkill...

HIH
M.

Comment: I actually tried this, but it seems the MANIFEST is generated after I "touched" the classes, so the jar is still stamped with different binary data... Is there a way to control the MANIFEST's time stamp?